# How to plot Tissot's indicatrix in different projections with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

it is my first question on stack overflow and I hope someone can help me out:)

I want to project the earth surface in matplotlib with the PlateCaree and Mercator-projection and add little circles to it to get the Tissot's indicatrix.

I have searched a lot, but I can't find the correct answer online. So far I can draw my circles, but they stay the same and do not stretch as they are supposed to do. Here is what I have so far:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import math

def main():
    # Setting values
    proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
    lonW = -90
    lonE = 90
    latS = -90
    latN = 90
    cLat = (latN + latS) / 2
    cLon = (lonW + lonE) / 2
    res = '110m'

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8.5))
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj)
    ax.gridlines( draw_labels=True, linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
    ax.set_extent([lonW, lonE, latS, latN], crs=proj)
    ax.coastlines(resolution=res, color='black')

    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES)

    # Adding a single coordinate
    ax.scatter(24.3, 61.83, color='red', marker='o', s=6, transform=proj, label='Hyytiälä')

    # Adding first circle
    center_lon, center_lat = 0, 0
    r = 10
    ax.add_patch(mpatches.Circle(xy=[center_lon, center_lat], radius=r, color='red', alpha=0.3, transform=proj, zorder=30))

    # Adding a second circle
    center_lon, center_lat = 0, 30
    r = 10
    ax.add_patch(mpatches.Circle(xy=[center_lon, center_lat], radius=r, color='red', alpha=0.3, transform=proj, zorder=30))

    # Adding a third circle
    center_lon, center_lat = 0, 60
    r = 10
    ax.add_patch(mpatches.Circle(xy=[center_lon, center_lat], radius=r, color='red', alpha=0.3, transform=proj, zorder=30))

    # Adding a last circle
    center_lon, center_lat = 0, 90
    r = 10
    ax.add_patch(mpatches.Circle(xy=[center_lon, center_lat], radius=r, color='red', alpha=0.3, transform=proj, zorder=30))
```

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cartopy already has this built-in as a dedicated method on any axes, so an even simpler approach would be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

config = {
    "Plate Carree": dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()),
    "Mercator": dict(projection=ccrs.Mercator()),
}

layout = [[name] for name in config.keys()]

fig, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    layout, figsize=(6,9), facecolor="w", dpi=100, 
    layout="compressed", per_subplot_kw=config, height_ratios=[1.2,2],
)

for name, ax in axs.items():
    
    ax.coastlines()
    ax.set_title(name)
    ax.tissot(alpha=.3, fc="C3")
```

[image]

I'm not sure if that's what you're after, you could do it manually by  drawing the circles as shown below. To do so you can replace `ax.tissot()` with the code below, using more or less the points you already defined:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from cartopy.geodesic import Geodesic
```

```py
    # in the axes loop:
    for lon, lat, r in [
        (0,0,10*110000),
        (0,30,10*110000),
        (0,60,10*110000),
        (0,89,10*110000), # 90° has a height of 0
    ]:

        circle_points = Geodesic().circle(lon=lon, lat=lat, radius=r)
        ax.add_geometries(
            (Polygon(circle_points),), facecolor='C3', alpha=.5,
            crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
        )
```

The radius should be in meters, which I've defined crudely defined as being 110000 m per degree, using a radius of 10 degrees.

[image]

edit: Here's an example of the automatic and more manual method that Cartopy uses:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from cartopy.geodesic import Geodesic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy
from pyproj import geod

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4), facecolor="w", dpi=100, layout="compressed", subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()))

radius = 300 # km
n_samples = 80
lons = (0, 0, 0, 0)
lats = (20, 40, 60, 80)

# auto
ax.tissot(rad_km=radius, lons=lons, lats=lats, n_samples=n_samples, fc='none', ec="C3", lw=2)

# manual
for lon, lat in zip(lons,lats):
    circle = Geodesic().circle(lon, lat, radius*1000., n_samples=n_samples)
    feature = cartopy.feature.ShapelyFeature([Polygon(circle)], ccrs.Geodetic(), fc='none', ec="C0", lw=2, linestyle="--")
    ax.add_feature(feature)


ax.coastlines(alpha=.5, lw=0.4)
ax.set_extent((-45,45,0,90), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image]

Comment: I rather want only single circles as I just wanted to compare it to tissot indicatrix to figure out if the singles circle i programmed in the projection are doing what they should do (if the local distortions are correct).

In the last two pictures I don't understand why the circles don't look as in the first two figures. Why isn't the circle at the north pole in the mercator projection not a circle anymore as in tissot and why is the circle at the north pole of the platecarree projection not an elipse as in tissot anymore?

Comment: That's because they are not valid for the same location. If you use the same location and radius, the result will be the same (see edit). It's still not clear to me what you're trying to do. Note that the definition of Cartopy is a little unusual (in my opinion) for showing the deformation of the large circle. But the more common definition can be achieved in the same way by just using a tiny radius, and then blow up the result in axes coordinates, that shows the deformation for the centroid. Matplotlib's `Circle` will by definition always be a circle, that won't work.